# How I can turn this code to MUI component with its css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this code to create a hero banner with its CSS, my project is using react and MUI for the front end. I'm not sure how I can convert this code to MUI, I tried but the styling is not working

HTML code :

```
      <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M321.39,56.44c58-10.79,114.16-30.13,172-41.86,82.39-16.72,168.19-17.73,250.45-.39C823.78,31,906.67,72,985.66,92.83c70.05,18.48,146.53,26.09,214.34,3V0H0V27.35A600.21,600.21,0,0,0,321.39,56.44Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

css code

```
  .custom-shape-divider-top-1664680360 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
  }
  
  .custom-shape-divider-top-1664680360 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(157% + 1.3px);
    height: 251px;
  }
  
  .custom-shape-divider-top-1664680360 .shape-fill {
    fill: #FFFFFF;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/1115700158761255786. You can convert svg icon and use it as icon also. secondly make a jsx component then call it as a component.